# Is there any functoriality of Stallings' twists?

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, knot-link

Suppose $L$ is an oriented link and $L'$ is a link obtained from the Stallings' twists.

Are there any functoriality of the twist operation on the links, such as functoriality between (1) homology groups $H_*(S^3 - L)$, $H_*(S^3 - L')$ of link complements, (2) Thurston norm or Alexander norm, or (3) Teichmuller polynomials if those links are fibered.

Any relation or induced maps are welcome even it is not functorial at all..

Thank you in advance.

EDIT---
The Stallings' twist in my settings is, if there is a link $L$ then choose a curve $C$ which is an unknot in $S^3$ and the linking number between $L$ is $0$.
Now thicken $C$ and we get a solid torus whose core is $C$.
The Dehn surgery of slope $\pm1$ along this torus is what I call "Stallings' twist".

For example, If $L$ is a torus link $(2, 2)$, which is in fact a Hopf link, then choose $C$ as the meridian of the torus.
Taking the twist $n$ times will yields a $(2, 2n+2)$ torus link.

Comment: Could you tell us your definition of "Stallings' twists"?

Comment: While you're at it, perhaps you could say what you mean by `functoriality' in this setting.

Comment: An orientation on a link determines a basis for the first homology; orientations are preserved by Stallings twists. So in that sense the homology groups you asked about are canonically identified.

Comment: Dear Ryan, I just editted my settings. If I understand it incorrectly please let me know. sorry for omitting the details.

Comment: Dear Danny, What I mean by functoriality is that after some operation the link changes, and I wonder if one can induce some maps on homology or Teichmuller polynomials or some other link invariants from the twisting operation.

Comment: In my understanding, one should first find a Seifert surface, and choose a simple closed Curve in it which is unknoted in $S^3$, and such that the normal framing (w.r.t the surface) is zero. The twist w.r.t this curve is a Stalling twist. It seems that this definition requires more than yours (the framing condition). Correct me please if I made a mistake.